# Switch window on Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am using Selenium with PhantomJS in Python.
I need to open a new window and control it.

For testing purposes, I'm doing so:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

driver.get('http://www.google.com.br')
handle = driver.execute_script('return window.open("http://www.pudim.com.br/", "any", "height = 450, width = 800, menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,location=no,resizable=yes");')
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
print(driver.current_url)
```

The above code works partially. The URL printed on the last message is `about: blank` as would be expected is `http://www.pudim.com.br/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there is *no built-in support* for selenium to work in multi-window (multi-tab) environment, fire up a new driver instead:

```
new_driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
new_driver.set_window_size(800, 450)
new_driver.get("http://www.pudim.com.br/")
```

Also, you current code is working for me:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
>>> 
>>> driver.get('http://www.google.com.br')
>>> handle = driver.execute_script('return window.open("http://www.pudim.com.br/", "any", "height = 450, width = 800, menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,location=no,resizable=yes");')
>>> driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
>>> print(driver.current_url)
http://www.pudim.com.br/
```

Most likely, this means that you are requesting the `current_url` at the time the page is not loaded yet. In this case, use an [`Explicit Wait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits) to wait for a specific element to appear on the page.

You can also increase the [page load wait timeout](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_page_load_timeout), but this is not quite reliable.

Comment: Thanks, but in my project that is not possible. I access a page with a search form and the result is given in a new window.

Comment: @KeplerBR okay, is the site public - meaning is there a way to share the link to that search functionality?

Comment: Sorry, but I can not because the site is not site public. The JS command executed in the return of the search is the same as the example.

Comment: @KeplerBR have you seen the updated answer? Does it help? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, making it wait works. Really that was the problem. Sorry about the delay to respond.

Comment: @alecxe depending on versions, trying to fire up a new driver kills the previous, unless you set a new port. I know that few things may change along time and maybe it worked on the time of the reply.