# python selenium phantomJS new tab not working

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm using selenium with the PhantomJS webdriver, and I've found that I cannot open a new tab using this webdriver. I'm using the standard line:

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
```

I use a Mac.

I have also tried this with Firefox and it works.

Any help to get it working with PhantomJS would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same issue just now, and I found a way that is, in my opinion, better than attempting to send keys to PhantomJS.

Remember, PhantomJS is a headless browser - no actual window is rendered for your OS to access via keyboard shortcuts.

That being said, every time a new tab/window is opened, it is added to the driver's window handles. Each window handle has a unique identifier.

You can easily just switch to the ID of that window (and back to your original window handler - if you wish to).

**Example**:

```
# Click a link that opens a new tab ...

# You'll see there's a new window handle!
print(driver.window_handles)

# Switch to the new window handle in the window_handles list
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

# Switch back to the original window
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

Then it's trivial to just check the driver's `current_url` to ensure you are on the right page, i.e.:

```
assert "www.stackoverflow.com" in driver.current_url
```

This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29125205/295246

Comment: Cuz PhantomJS is javascript powered, you can always open a new windows with `driver.execute_script('window.open("http://your-url.dot")');` in place of "Click a link that opens a new tab". It's also better to just name your handles than rely on the url, but is ok too.

Comment: That doesn't actually answer how to open the new window, and doing via javascript like i said does cause to lost the previous userAgent (and more things for sure) in capabilities. I think that attaching a dummy `target='_blank'` link and clicking it would be a good way to do it.